# ios 8.4.1 click twice needed on anchor tag

Tags: ios, web, tags, click, anchor

We have this public webpage www.tv2bornholm.dk which works fine on all platforms also ipads with up to IOS 8.4. But with the new 8.4.1 on ipads and iphones you need to click/tap twice on the links in the list on the right.

I cannot locate the problem. The link is just a simple anchor tag, which should work with a single tap. (below an single link list element)

```
<li class="newsRow"><span id="time">12:39</span><a id="newsLink" href="/?newsID=93929">Pigefodbold: Nexøspiller udtaget til U17</a></li>
```

We do use some hover effects by way of CSS, but I cannot see why this should be the reason. I have also read that the 8.4.1 update does do stuff to webkit/safari to prevent malicious tap/clicks, but I cannot see how to fix our code.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and was able to find a solution in this [Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/SE-JnjXwsdU/LDPtM7GSAgAJ). The solution was to add a global CSS rule to reset the z-index:

```
* {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

As mentioned in the forum thread, this likely had something to do with the security bug fix released in iOS 8.4.1 that is detailed [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205030) (search for "A malicious website can make a tap event produce a synthetic click on another page").

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was that we had `opacity: 0.8` on `:hover` or `:focus`. Any clicks or touches on a link with `opacity` set to less than 1 on `:hover` or `:focus` are also recognized as synthetic clicks on ios 8.4.1.

Changing the those states back to `opacity: 1` and using `rgba()` colors instead fixed the problem in my case!